# Laravel 5.1 How to update the value of a select option field based on the selected item in another select option field?

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have two select option field in a from, one for the province and one for the city. There are two tables which corresponds to this fields.

```
//The province table schema 
Schema::create('provinces', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('province', 100);
            $table->timestamps();
//The city table schema
Schema::create('cities', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('city', 20);
            $table->smallInteger('province_id')->unsigned();
            $table->index('province_id');
            $table->timestamps();
```

These tables are pre-populated with the name of provinces, cities and their related province id. In my form I need that after selecting a province, the city field be updated with a list of that province cities. How can I do this?

```
//The create method in controller
 public function create()
    {
        $provinces=Province::lists('province', 'id')->all();
        $cities=City::lists('city', 'id');
        return view('profile.create', compact('provinces', 'cities'));
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any experience with javascript?

Comment: @ross-wilson Unfortunately I have very little experience with Javascript

Comment: To do something like following you would need to use javascript, otherwise you would have to create a form wizard (i.e. multiple steps/pages).

Comment: You should use JS or jQuery to do this